# Removing "unnamed: #" when writing to CSV using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV file that I'm updating every day from some data being scraped from a website.  The format for the file is not ideal, but unfortunately there are other dependencies that make it so I can't change the way the numbers are supposed to be formatted.  I am reading the CSV that I already have every day, and then updating it with the data from each new day as the info comes out.  The file is formatted as below:

```
2015-06-29|         |  2015-06-28|         |  2015-06-27|         ...
col1      |  col2   |  col1      |  col2   |  col1      |  col2
10        |  3      |  103.4     |  6.6    |  103.2     |  4.3
1028      |  5      |  102.4     |  6.2    |  103.3     |  2.2
90        |  6      |  91.7      |  5.0    |  93.1      |  2.4
105       |  1      |  100.8     |  5.5    |  100.9     |  1.7
345       |  7      |  103.0     |  6.1    |  102.9     |  6.3
53        |  3      |  106.0     |  8.6    |  105.3     |  7.6
110       |  5      |  113.0     |  9.1    |  110.9     |  6.7
32        |  4      |  3.9       |  1.8    |  3.5       |  2.9
...
```

And when a new day comes, I will have the following saved in a separate Pandas dataframe:

```
2015-06-30|        
col1      |  col2 
1         |  3     
28        |  5     
901       |  6     
15        |  1     
45        |  7      
533       |  3     
15        |  5  
75        |  4
```

I am just trying to insert these two rows to the left of the most recent entries, and then save over the previous file.  I'm not having any trouble with this, but I am getting "unnamed: #" in the columns next to the dates instead of just an empty cell like this:

```
2015-06-29|         |  2015-06-28|  unnamed:0      |  2015-06-27| unnamed:1
col1      |  col2   |  col1      |  col2           |  col1      |  col2
10        |  3      |  103.4     |  6.6            |  103.2     |  4.3
1028      |  5      |  102.4     |  6.2            |  103.3     |  2.2
90        |  6      |  91.7      |  5.0            |  93.1      |  2.4
105       |  1      |  100.8     |  5.5            |  100.9     |  1.7
345       |  7      |  103.0     |  6.1            |  102.9     |  6.3
53        |  3      |  106.0     |  8.6            |  105.3     |  7.6
110       |  5      |  113.0     |  9.1            |  110.9     |  6.7
32        |  4      |  3.9       |  1.8            |  3.5       |  2.9
```

How can I get rid of these cell values and keep the empty cells instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the CSV with  `header=None` then empty cells get filled with `NaN`, instead of `"Unnamed:X"`:

```
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s*[|]\s*', header=None)
#             0     1           2     3           4     5
# 0  2015-06-29   NaN  2015-06-28   NaN  2015-06-27   NaN
# 1        col1  col2        col1  col2        col1  col2
# 2          10     3       103.4   6.6       103.2   4.3
# ...
```

You could then slice the first two rows from the rest of the dataframe:

```
    columns = df.iloc[:2]
    df = df.iloc[2:]
```

replace the `NaN`s with empty strings by calling `fillna`,

```
    columns = columns.fillna('')
```

and then make the columns a MultiIndex:

```
    columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(columns.values.tolist())
    df.columns = columns
```

---

For example, if `data` has contents

```
2015-06-29|         |  2015-06-28|         |  2015-06-27|         
col1      |  col2   |  col1      |  col2   |  col1      |  col2
10        |  3      |  103.4     |  6.6    |  103.2     |  4.3
1028      |  5      |  102.4     |  6.2    |  103.3     |  2.2
90        |  6      |  91.7      |  5.0    |  93.1      |  2.4
105       |  1      |  100.8     |  5.5    |  100.9     |  1.7
345       |  7      |  103.0     |  6.1    |  102.9     |  6.3
53        |  3      |  106.0     |  8.6    |  105.3     |  7.6
110       |  5      |  113.0     |  9.1    |  110.9     |  6.7
32        |  4      |  3.9       |  1.8    |  3.5       |  2.9
```

and `data2` has contents

```
2015-06-30|        
col1      |  col2 
1         |  3     
28        |  5     
901       |  6     
15        |  1     
45        |  7      
533       |  3     
15        |  5  
75        |  4
```

then

```
import pandas as pd

def read_multiheader(filepath_or_buffer, num_header_rows=2, encoding=None):
    from pandas.io.common import get_filepath_or_buffer
    filepath_or_buffer, _ = get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding)
    df = pd.read_table(filepath_or_buffer, sep='\s*[|]\s*', header=None)
    columns = df.iloc[:num_header_rows]
    columns = columns.fillna('')
    columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(columns.values.tolist())
    df = df.iloc[num_header_rows:]
    df.columns = columns
    return df

df = read_multiheader('data')
df2 = read_multiheader('data2')
newdf = pd.concat([df2, df], axis=1)
print(newdf)
```

yields

```
  2015-06-30      2015-06-29      2015-06-28      2015-06-27     
        col1 col2       col1 col2       col1 col2       col1 col2
2          1    3         10    3      103.4  6.6      103.2  4.3
3         28    5       1028    5      102.4  6.2      103.3  2.2
4        901    6         90    6       91.7  5.0       93.1  2.4
5         15    1        105    1      100.8  5.5      100.9  1.7
6         45    7        345    7      103.0  6.1      102.9  6.3
7        533    3         53    3      106.0  8.6      105.3  7.6
8         15    5        110    5      113.0  9.1      110.9  6.7
9         75    4         32    4        3.9  1.8        3.5  2.9
```

Comment: This is an amazing answer, so thank you for that.  However, I am getting an error that when I call your `read_multiheader`: "Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile'> type".  Apparently an ExcelFile isn't a file-like object?  Any quick modifications I can make to this so it works?

Comment: Excel files may be loaded into Pandas DataFrame using [`pd.ExcelFile.parse`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html#pandas-excelfile-parse) instead of `pd.read_table`.