# pandas is filling empty cells in my csv with "Unnamed:"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My original csv:

```
a, b, c
d, , c
, , l
```

after running:

```
df = pd.read_csv("original.csv", header=[0, 1, 2], index_col=[0])
ds = df.sample(frac=1)
ds.to_csv("shuffled_scenarios.csv")
```

it becomes this:

```
a, b, c
d, Unnamed: 1_level_1, c,
Unnamed: 0_level_2, Unnamed: 1_level_2, l
```

Basically, it is adding "Unnamed:..." where I used to have empty cells. How do I set it to keep these empty cells untouched or convert them back to their original form?

Comment: See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325372/removing-unnamed-when-writing-to-csv-using-pandas)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing "unnamed: #" when writing to CSV using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325372/removing-unnamed-when-writing-to-csv-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv("original.csv", header=None)
```

I think you have to read the csv with header none